# Use Generics to achieve data in required JSON format

Tags: c#, json, .net, generics, anonymous-types

I have a generic class say

```
public class Generic<T>
{
   public T Data {get; set;}
}
```

Suppose I have an anonymous object like

```
var r1 = new {
    A = lstA,
        validation = null as ValidationError
    }

var r2 =  new {
    B = lstB,
        validation = null as ValidationError
    }
```

And I assigned as below

```
Generic<object> g1 = new Generic<object>
g1.Data = r1

Generic<object> g2 = new Generic<object>
g2.Data = r2
```

When I serialize above g1 using JsonSerialize.Serialize (g1), I got output

```
{
   "Data":{
      "A":[
         {
            
         }
      ],
      "validation":null
   }
}

{
   "Data":{
      "B":[
         {
            
         }
      ],
      "validation":null
   }
}
```

Right now I achieved above JSON format by assigning anonymous r1 to g1.Data. Is it possible to achieve above JSON format by just using generics?

The name "A" in above JSON format differ in each cases. It can be "A"in one case, "B" in another case etc.

I tried above code and achieved required JSON format using anonymous type and Generics. Would like to know is it possible to achieve above JSON format by usibg generics alone or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just define two classes, one containing the property A and the other containing the property B. The question seems to have nothing to do with generic.

Comment: @shingo I think he means that the keys "A", "B" are dynamic and can be anything like xyz

Comment: @DanialAhmed I'm just confused about "using generics alone".

Comment: keys A, B are dynamic as Danial said

Comment: It's a little unclear what your intention is. However, it sounds like your only bothered about the property name (A or B) being something generic once serialized and not before. If so, you could decorate the property with `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "YourName")]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to use `Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();` ?

```
Generic<object> g1 = new Generic<object>;
g1.Data = r1

Generic<object> g2 = new Generic<object>;
g2.Data = r2

dic.Add("A", g1);
dic.Add("B", g2);
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OPs question of how effectively the same type of object with differing property names can be represented the same way in JSON.

Comment: With dictionary i am able to achieve json data in required format

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use generics. It sounds like you just want the property name to be the same, whether it's A, B or Elephant for that particular property (and others).

If you have to use dynamic objects then look at creating a custom contract resolver that can rename the property: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm

Alternatively, you can just use the `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "YourName")]` attribute from **Newtonsoft.Json**. Here's an example:

```
internal class SomethingA
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "C")]
    public IList<int> A { get; set; }
}

internal class SomethingB
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "C")]
    public IList<int> B { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var somethingA = new SomethingA { A = new List<int> { 1, 2 } };
        var somethingB = new SomethingB { B = new List<int> { 3, 4 } };

        var aSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(somethingA); // gives {"C":[1,2]}
        var bSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(somethingB); // gives {"C":[3,4]}
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this out and will let you know. Thank you all for the replies